# mock-maker-inline makes test fail with "NotAMockException Argument passed to Mockito.mockingDetails() should be a mock" on non-final non-static class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a JUnit test where I have 5 mocks and one of mocked classes is final, I enabled mock-maker-inline to overcome that problem and now test passes but at the end of test execution I also get NotAMockException at:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument passed to Mockito.mockingDetails() should be a mock, but is an instance of class ...Locals!
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$2.testFinished(DefaultInternalRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testFinished(SynchronizedRunListener.java:56)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$7.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFinished(RunNotifier.java:187)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.EachTestNotifier.fireTestFinished(EachTestNotifier.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:80)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
...
```

The mocking is very simple:

```
    @Mock
    private Locals locals; //class

    @Mock
    private Globals globals; // class

    @Mock
    private Cache cache; // interface

    @Mock
    private Reminds reminds; // final class

    @Mock
    private Employeereminds employeereminds; // class
```

... followed by couple of when().thenReturn() setups to make it work together

During the test mocks looks like this:

```
locals = {Locals@3233} 
globals = {Globals@3234} 
cache = {Cache$MockitoMock$665734991@3237} "cache"
reminds = {Reminds@3235} 
employeereminds = {Employeereminds@3236}
```

I am using Mockito 2.25.0 also tried 2.28.2 but no difference.

I can refactor my test to also test the content of final class but I prefer my test isolated. I could also use powermock but have seen similar problems reported with powermock.

Did anybody stumble upon such issue and found a decent workaround?

**EDIT:** I did some more investigation, I removed `Locals` Mock and got same error on `Globals` mock. Then I removed `Globals` mock and got (!?) following exception (@ v2.28.2):

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument passed to Mockito.mockingDetails() should be a mock, but is an instance of class Cache$MockitoMock$149288076!

    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$2.testFinished(DefaultInternalRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testFinished(SynchronizedRunListener.java:56)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$7.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFinished(RunNotifier.java:187)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.EachTestNotifier.fireTestFinished(EachTestNotifier.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:80)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    ...
```

Comment: For now I switched from Strict to Silent runner but that is not the solution I am fond of.

Comment: Can you show the Locals class and its test?

Comment: Hi, I did some exclusions from the test to pinpoint the problem and it seems it is not specific to Locals class as it is raised on pretty much every mock, even complaining that `Cache` should be a mock but it is `Cache$MockitoMock$149288076`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found the issue:
I was invoking

```
Mockito.framework().clearInlineMocks();
```

in a code invoked by `@After` annotation, but the correct way is to do it in code invoked by `@AfterClass` annotation, otherwise Mockito own verification is run after you cleared the mocks.

Comment: Thanks. Was smashing my head off the wall on this one. 


`@AfterClass
 void afterClass () {
  Mockito.framework ().clearInlineMocks ();
 }`